# awk/gawk array concatenation into string fail

Tags: awk

I want to concatenate a array into a string in gawk
have the array **a** [ ABC, DEF, GHI ]
and want a string like "ABC DEF GHI"

*here I simplified the pipe feeding with 'echo' for demonstration purpouses:*

> - test... working OK (no concatenation, only output)
>
>   @(echo ABC & echo DEF & echo GHI) | gawk '{a[$0]++} END { for( f in a )  print f; }'

> - now try to concatenate
>
>   @(echo ABC & echo DEF & echo GHI) | gawk '{a[$0]++} END { for( f in a ) b=(b f); print b; }'

just returns the 1st string in the array 'a'...
?any ideas on how to do this...

Comment: Why are you doing this vs just `echo 'ABC DEF GHI'`? What kind of system are you on that has the syntax `@(echo ABC & echo DEF & echo GHI)` to create a pipe of input to awk? On a Unix system there's a few different things that `for( f in a ) b=(b f); print b` might do given a pipe of input such as I assume `@(echo ABC & echo DEF & echo GHI)` produces on your system but what it definitely will NOT do is just print `the 1st string in the array 'a'`

Comment: The only way that last command would **appear** to only print `ABC` would be if your system uses DOS line endings and the `for (f in a)` was shuffling  the input order such that `ABC` is visited last. Pipe the output to `cat -v` and look for `^M`s to see if that's the case.

Comment: hi @Ed... I'm at a Windows CLI/shell using gawk from Cygwin or GNU.... I cant use ${a[@]}... and the concatenation must happen from inside gawk... the problem is that the 'b' variable would not accumulate the values... even putting the 'accumulation' out of the immediate variable assign wasn't successful -->> find x* | awk 'BEGIN {} {!x[$0]++} END { s=""; for( f in x ) s=sprintf("%s%s", a, f); print s }'... ?any more ideas??

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have something like `find` that is is producing several strings and you want to concatenate or join those several strings into a space delimited single string?

Comment: I never use Windows CLI (on any Windows box I first install Cygwin and then run Unix commands within that) but I hear Windows has some arcane quoting rules and because of that the usual advice to anyone on Windows is to save any script in a file and execute is `awk -f scriptFile input` instead of `awk 'script' input`. One thing I THINK I've seen in the past is that in Windows scripts have to be wrapped in double quotes rather than single and then you have to escape double quotes (and other things?) within the script but idk, I might be misremembering.

Comment: sorry for the misleading... just replace 'find *' with 'dir /s *' .... it just output filenames...

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to print the concatenated values of a Unix shell array such as created by:

```
$ a=(ABC DEF GHI)
```

then just do:

```
$ echo "${a[*]}"
ABC DEF GHI
```

If you want to concatenate multiple input lines as produced by:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

with awk for some reason then there's several options including:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" | awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? OFS : ""), $0} END{print ""}'
ABC DEF GHI

$ printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" | awk '{b=(NR>1 ? b OFS : "") $0} END{print b}'
ABC DEF GHI

$ printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" | awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) b=(i>1 ? b OFS : "") a[i]; print b}'
ABC DEF GHI

$ printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" | awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) printf "%s%s", (i>1 ? OFS : ""), a[i]; print ""}'
ABC DEF GHI
```

If none of that is what you're trying to do then please edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: hi @Ed... I'm at a Windows CLI/shell using gawk from Cygwin or GNU.... I cant use ${a[@]}... and the concatenation must happen from inside gawk... the problem is that the 'b' variable would not accumulate the values... even putting the 'accumulation' out of the immediate variable assign wasn't successful -->> find x* | awk 'BEGIN {} {!x[$0]++} END { s=""; for( f in x ) s=sprintf("%s%s", a, f); print s }'... ?any more ideas??

Comment: Sounds like you're being bitten by Windows quoting rules. Save the awk script (`{a[NR]=$0 ... print ""}`) in a file named `scriptFile` and and execute it as `awk -f scriptFile` instead of `awk 'script'` to avoid that issue.